# I am installing yii framework, but it shows Index of / instead

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I copied all required files to my debian server. 
/requirments.php shows 
"Your server configuration satisfies the minimum requirements by this application."
But still when I open my-domain.com it shows "Index of /" and directory structure instead of starting a yii application.

What am I missing

Comment: you need to point the web directory either via a symlink or read [this](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-shared-hosting#deploying-a-basic-project-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that mode_rewrite was not enabled from Apache.
As I enabled it, it started working.